Confused about the stationarity and unit root concepts
Say that I consider a white noise process, which by definition is stationary.
I'm confused by the fact that if I use the Dickey-Fuller test, technically speaking I should fail to reject the null hypothesis.
This is a consequence of assuming that the series is an autoregressive process. Same thing would happen for instance, if I consider a white noise process around a deterministic trend.
In that case I could use an DF test with drift, but still if I do the math the by construction the coefficient $\gamma$ on my DF test will be equal to  0.
So I fail the test even if the series is stationary around q trend.
What am I missing?

Hi: I think you need to write out the equations you are referring to because the DGPs that you are referring to don't have coefficients to be tested so it's not clear to me how you are running the DF test on them ?
